# Allow communication on specific ports between two Docker containers on different bridge networks

Tags: docker, docker-network

Preface: This question is similar to [Allow communication between two docker bridge networks using docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37657914/allow-communication-between-two-docker-bridge-networks-using-docker-compose) but that question is 4+ years old so I felt it best to ask a new question.

I have two **bridge** networks and two containers, one on each network. I am trying to figure out how to make a port on one container available to another container.

```
$ docker network create net1
$ docker network create net2

$ docker run -it -d --net=net1 --name container1 -p 1234:80 ....
$ docker run -it -d --net=net2 --name container2 -p 5678:80 ....
```

Now, I'd like `container1` to be able to make a call to `container2:80` and `container2:4321` but I am not sure how to do that.

I am trying to do this **without** using the macvlan driver.

Comment: Why not use a third network and put both containers there?

Comment: I want to limit what talking each container can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a lesser restriction in my case where I open up certain port numbers in all containers. The containers communicate with each other by using the host IP and the exposed port number.

In my case, on top connecting to the custom network, I also connect the containers to the default `bridge` network. The default network does not allow communication between the containers.

Then in iptables, I create a new pipeline and pipe docker0 (the `bridge` network) to it

```
-F FILTERS
-A DOCKER-USER -i docker0 -o docker0 -j FILTERS
```

And allow the whitelisted port numbers

```
-A FILTERS -p tcp --dport 1234 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment container1
-A FILTERS -p tcp --dport 5678 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment container2
```

You can try tightening the restriction, by

- not connecting the default `bridge` network
- finding the network interface of `net1` and `net2` via `ip link show` and `ifconfig`
- changing the pipeline to

```
-F CONTAINER1-CONTAINER2
-F CONTAINER2-CONTAINER1
-A DOCKER-USER -i br-xxxx -o br-yyyy -j CONTAINER1-CONTAINER2
-A DOCKER-USER -i br-yyyy -o br-xxxx -j CONTAINER2-CONTAINER1
```

- Modifying the port list to

```
-A CONTAINER2-CONTAINER1 -p tcp --dport 1234 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment container1
-A CONTAINER1-CONTAINER2 -p tcp --dport 5678 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment container2
```

Comment: Thanks. I really need to learn `iptables` commands better. So far I've been using UFW but that doesn't jive with Docker.